# Google Sheet Excel AVERAGE formula

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I just want to ask if why does the result of the formula is not the same? I used 95, 93, 95, 95, 96, 94 as the value.

Formula 1:
`=IF(ISERROR(AVERAGE(I11,N11,S11,X11,AC11,AH11,AM11,AR11,AW11)),"0",AVERAGE(I11,N11,S11,X11,ACB11,AH11,AM11,AR11,AW11))`

For Formula 1, I need to get the value by cell.

Here's the value for each cell:

I11 = 93, N11 = 95, S11 = none, X11 = 95, AC11 = 96, AH11 = 94, AM11 = none, AR11 = none and AW11 = 95

Formula 2:
`=IFERROR(ROUND(AVERAGE(J17:J25),0),"")`

Result: `Formula 1 is 94.40` while `Formula 2 is 95`

Comment: Formula 1 isn't using the values you listed. The average of those values is 94.6666 not 94.4.

Comment: @Loocid yes, but the formula and the selection of cells are correct. The question has been updated with the cell value. Hope it can help.

Comment: Ah, you have a typo. Formula 1 has `ACB11`, rather than `AC11`.

Comment: @Loocid oh! thank you! I didn't saw that. It works fine now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(I11, N11, S11, X11, AC11, AH11, AM11, AR11, AW11), 0)
```